# Is a minus sign attached to the variable or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions

This seems like such a simple question but I'm struggling with it. In an algebraic formula if there is a - in front of the coefficient of a variable is that a -6 times the variable or take away 6 times the variable. I'll show an example below:

y = -6x + 2

So, in this case, is the equation saying take away 6 times x
Or is it saying -6 times x?

The primary reason I ask is when substituting values into the quadratic formula you, of course, take the - sign with it. But in other cases, it feels like you are taking away.

edit:
A better way of writing it is further into the equation so in the case:
y = 6x-6z
In this case is this 6x + (-6)*z or 6x - (6z)

Comment: "take away $6$ times $x$".... taking it away from **what**?

Comment: When you write, e.g., $y=mx+b$ , the $m$ is a multiplicative factor.  Could be positive or, as in your case, negative.  Not sure what you mean by "take away" in this context.

Comment: $6x-6z = 6x+(-6)\times z = 6x-(6z)$.  They all mean the same thing.  If you insist on there being a semantic difference between them, then you have the option to pick whichever makes you the most comfortable as it doesn't matter in the end.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction you're drawing: "$-(6x)$" and "$(-6)x$" are the same thing.

Comment: So as long as you take the minus sign with the coefficient when substituting it into another formula it doesn't really matter? I think that answers what I was struggling with, the fact the + sign is always there just omitted when not needed.

Comment: If you want to get technical, the way we often formally define subtraction in the first place is that $a - b$ is defined as $a + (\color{red}{-}b)$ where here the minus sign $-$ is treated differently than the additive inverse sign $\color{red}{-}$.  They just happen in common practice to use the same symbol but should be interpreted differently.  But, in writing it in this formal fashion, it clutters the expression.  $a-b$ is much easier to read than $a+(\color{red}{-}b)$, especially when $a$ and $b$ are themselves much more complicated expressions.

Comment: Yes this is why I was struggling because when taking coefficients from more complicated formulas into the quadratic formula, I didn't understand why the minus sign came with it. To me it looked like you were subtracting a positive coefficient, but this makes much more sense thank you.

Comment: If you are concerned about the grammar of this equation you should also be concerned about the kinds of things $x$ and $y$ are - what is it that allows them to be combined with coefficients in equations? And it is also material to your question what kinds of coefficients are allowed - are they integers or rational numbers or real numbers, for example. If only positive integers were allowed as coefficients you'd have to attach the minus sign to the valid expression $6x$ (and perhaps explain what it meant) because $(-6)x$ would not be allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get technical, the way we often formally define subtraction in the first place is that a−b
is defined as a+(−b) where here the minus sign − is treated differently than the additive inverse sign −. They just happen in common practice to use the same symbol but should be interpreted differently. But, in writing it in this formal fashion, it clutters the expression. a−b is much easier to read than a+(−b), especially when a and b are themselves much more complicated expressions. – JMoravitz 7 mins ago

The question I was struggling with was answered in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Any factor multiplying a variable would be considered as a multiplier and not attached to the variable. In your example, you can think of -6 as (-1)(6) in which -1 is a factor by itself. Any formula involving -x should be a simple extension of the formula involving x since (-1) is a quite common factor.